# For a mod other user was rude. I objected but now my post is gone. Why is my post unable to be edited without peer review?

Tags: discussion, food-safety

Why is my post not listed under my questions? Why can’t I delete it?

I tried to put this in meta, but the site won't let me ask a question there.  I was NOT permitted to add a comment to any post accept mine. NOW the site won't even let me change my post without it being peer reviewed. I was able to change it earlier. I know this because there was a typo and I changed that. **Why???**

If a user is not allowed to add to comments, it is not helpful to come tell them you should put your reply in comments. Especially if you aren’t going to answer the original question.

Jumping on a new user is like cyber bullying, and is not “nice”. Which you claim is the rule. New users can ask question and add answers. If you don’t want new members, then you should close membership.

Comment: Hi HangryLady, you are right that this post is meant to be on Meta. See https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta, especially the end: the reason you weren't able to post here is that we require a first tiny bit of reputation for it, as a spam-prevention measure. Since your post is a legitimate Meta matter, I migrated it for you.

Comment: Thanks. Can you delete my original question about the jar of pasta sauce, since you are a Mod? Delete the whole thread? There is no delete question link when I view it. And I can't even edit the question. A user was rude but all of my comments were deleted but none of theirs.  I did not believe I was beginning a controversial discussion when I asked about jarred pasta sauce food safety.

Comment: @rumtscho my question doesn’t even appear under my list of questions I asked. I am the one who originally asked it though. Would you delete the original question and thread please? I think it is not right that a newbie is bullied and then can't reply. My comments were deleted but other people's comments were left. I'd like the whole question to be removed. Thank you.

Comment: @HangryLady For what it's worth, as far as I can tell you've asked a fine question in asking about the jar of pasta sauce. I'm not aware of the context of the rest of what happened, but I think it would be a shame to delete a perfectly good question/answer combo! Perhaps the context I'm missing is key here, however.

Comment: @onyz the problem is that another user was unnecessarily rude. I called her own it and then others users backed her up. I didn’t come here to be bullied. If I’m not going to be treated fairly then the question should be removed. I’m not being treated fairly just based on other being allowed  to delete or edit MY own post.

Comment: @HangryLady I'm very sorry to hear that. It's never fun when a new community isn't as welcoming as it should be. I can remember when I first joined StackExchange the experience was pretty much just as awful as you're describing. It's weird and rude. For what it's worth, the argument in the comments has since been deleted (rude people included) as far as I can tell. I'm not sure if this would be against the rules or anything, but I would be interested to know what the other user said specifically- it's possible that maybe there was just a misunderstanding?

Comment: @HangryLady I will note that as far as I'm aware it's not actually possible for moderators to prevent users from deleting or editing posts/comments/etc. Those functions are all done automatically by the StackExchange website for all users. Still, it's unfortunate that you're not having a good experience. I hope you can find something that works better for you.

Comment: @onyx for what it’s worth. Luciano confirmed that the delete button should be there but isn’t. My comments are gone. The other comments are just hidden and I can’t edit my question.  I've never joined a new community and had it respond so nastily immediately. If that happens to others too, then that’s sad. Sad that it happened to you. Surprised anyone would stay after that.

Comment: You have been pointed to the tour and help pages, and have been provided various links and information regarding how the site works (and why you can't delete your question). It's no different for you than anyone else. While we welcome new users, I must ask that you be respectful of others.

Comment: @HangryLady as described in the link Sneftel posted, and in Stephie's answer, deleting your question would be against our policy and no moderator would agree to such a deletion. I don't know why Luciano can see the link, but chances are, it may not actually lead to deletion if he clicks it. In any case, we are bound by how the system is supposed to work. I know you regret having started the conversation and wish to make it un-happen. This is not possible. It did happen, other people invested their time in it, and it will continue have value for them and for new readers. So the question stays.

Comment: As the "rude" user in question, should I answer/comment providing my point of view, or will that just continue the argument unnecessarily?

Comment: @Elenna123 the question is mainly about edits and deletion, not any other events. You may of course answer, but it should clearly address the question. The „answer the question“ rule applies here as well.

Comment: @Elenna123 personally, I'd advise not spending any more time on this.

Comment: @rumtscho I can see the delete button _on my questions_, not on HangryLady's. I was just confirming that one should see the button in their own question, unless there's something I'm missing (I have been a user in other SE's for a while, I don't know if it's different for a completely new user). Edit: clearly I should've read the answers below

Answer (score 12):

To answer parts of the literal question:
[You can’t edit a post after the first few minutes if you aren’t registered.](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/why-register) You also can’t comment on it without the “comment everywhere” privilege or delete it. That simple.

*Edit to clarify:*

- The original question about the jar of pasta sauce was posted by an **unregistered** account, note the turquoise gravatar.
- The posts after that we’re posted by a **registered** account with the same chosen user name, which has a pink gravatar.

That means that you can see all posts, including deleted posts younger than 60 days, that were posted by the *registered* account when logging in as such.  You can also edit them or comment on them.
You can’t see deleted posts by your *unregistered* account. For the system, they are from two distinct users. Which means you can perform only those actions that you could do with any other post and that depends on what your privileges permit.

---

But looking at the other things that came up, maybe this needs a longer answer, covering more than just the question per se.

First, your actual question is quite interesting and it would be a pity to lose it. As it has an answer and that answer has an upvote, you can’t delete it. See [here](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-questions) for details.

Second, all SE sites have a very clear format, which is basically “one question on top and multiple answers below”. This automatically means that all posts in the answer section that are not actual answers to the question will be removed. The community members with enough reputation (“points”) can and will do that via votes and/or flags, or a moderator can do that, if they happen to see it. And this deletion is not negotiable, sorry.

Third, comments are per definition temporary. They are intended for clarification or suggesting improvements. They can be removed any time and without prior warning. The remaining comments under your deleted non-answer starting with “Thank you” weren’t removed manually as they were deleted together with the post.

Four, there is the question about rudeness. Some comments were clearly outside what is considered a respectful discussion, calling users “gestapo” or “liar” when they simply point out something that doesn’t fit the site’s rules is not ok and never will be. These comments were correctly flagged as rude by a user and handled by a moderator accordingly.

It is within your rights to delete some<sup>1</sup> of your posts. If you happen to be using the app (instead of the website), the “delete” can be tricky to find, it’s the little ‘x’. Maybe this screenshot will help?
[image]

It’s a known issue, but I don’t know when or if it will be fixed.

———-

<sup>1</sup> Again: Within the limits outlined [here](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-questions).

Comment: Yes, I have deleted some of your content. Non-answers and rude comments. That’s not targeting, that’s my task as moderator. But I didn’t do *anything* to you posts apart from that.

Comment: I didn’t make any rude comments. I asked a question NICELY. And I said thank you and clarified in the only way possible. The elenna123 was the one that was rude. And you are rude. Just delete the whole question thread! It wasn’t answered properly.

Comment: @HangryLady I see that the answers and comments you are getting from Stephie and other users make you angry. This is not the same as being rude. I can see all posts on your jar question and here, including the deleted comments you and the others made. None of their posts are rude, but several of yours are. I get it that our system can be confusing for new users, since it is structured in ways you may not have encountered before. The purpose of this post, and most of the others, are to explain these rules to you, nothing more and nothing less.

Comment: @rumtscho  I asked 1 on topic q. And gave 1 nice follow up reply including thank you.  Afterward, Elena's whole comment was rude and wrong. Cindy followed me around to every comment to tell me inaccurate info. She didn’t try to answer the jar q. I'm not asking you to take my side but the whole thing should be deleted because it didn’t require all of this nonsense. It’s only a jar of pasta sauce.

Comment: @HangryLady we won’t delete your questions for the reasons outlined [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that).

Comment: @HangryLady I hope that my edit now clarifies a bit why you may have run into the “can’t see the post” / “can’t edit” dilemma. We are all trying to *help*. Please stop calling us liars.

Answer (score 8):

Please read [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that), particularly the sections of the accepted answer discussing "When can't I delete my own post?" and "If I flag my question with a request to delete it, what will happen?". Questions and answers are meant to help the community at large, not just the original poster.

Comment: @HangryLady Please access the link provided by Sneftel. It explains why you can't delete your question - it has an answer with upvoted. Your post was in no way 'targeted'. And, no, everyone else can't delete their own questions regardless of answers or votes. That, too, is explained in the linked Q/A.